# Google Pay API AutoResolveHelper lifecycle

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I am using Stripe on my Android application for Google payment, it works just fine. The code can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/google-pay), it is quite forward. Basically here is my code:

```
PaymentDataRequest request = createPaymentDataRequest();
    if (request != null)
        AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request), activity, LOAD_GOOGLE_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

My problem is that the fragment that displays the credit card information coming from Google pay is quite long to display, and so I would like to display a dialogProgress that will dismiss as soon as Google payment fragment is displayed, however I don't know how to hook to this mecanism to dismiss my dialog as soon as Google payment fragment is actually displayed.

Comment: Since the Google Pay dialog will always be on top, do you really need to dismiss your dialog *as soon as* it's displayed? If you dismiss it right after the Google Pay dialog is dismissed (either as success or failure), you get more or less the same result UX-wise (since, again, the Google Pay dialog is always on top of your app).

Comment: Thanx @fstanis : Your response solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Google Pay dialog will always be on top, it doesn't make much of a difference if you dismiss your own dialog before or after it's displayed.

A good approach is to dismiss your own dialog after the Google Pay dialog is dismissed (either as success or failure). This way, you get more or less the same result UX-wise (since, again, the Google Pay dialog is always on top of your app).